# Need Help replicating some itertools functions

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to input the number and order for executing the formulas for permutation and combination. I need to generate the output using functions, but not getting the output. I do not want to use `itertools`.

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n < 0):
        print ("Please, Enter a positive value.")
    elif (n == 0 or n == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)

def permutation(n,r):
    perm = int(factorial(n) / factorial(n-r))
    return perm

def combination(p,q):
    com = int(permutation(p,q) / factorial(q))
    return com

num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
order = int(input("Enter the order: "))
print ("Make a choice, 1 for PERMUTATION and 2 for COMBINATION")
user_input = int(input("Enter the choice: "))
print (user_input)
if (user_input == 1):
    permutation(num,order)
elif (user_input == 2):
    combination(num,order)
else:
    print ("Enter a valid choice")
```

Comment: You need to *print* the return value of `permutation` and `combination`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not assigning the result of your calls to the `permutation` and `combination` functions to anything. Either pass them straight into `print()` or assign them and then print that variable.

```
def factorial(n):
    if (n < 0):
        print ("Please, Enter a positive value.")
    elif (n == 0 or n == 1):
        return 1
    else:
        return n*factorial(n-1)

def permutation(n,r):
    perm = int(factorial(n) / factorial(n-r))
    return perm

def combination(p,q):
    com = int(permutation(p,q) / factorial(q))
    return com

num = int(input("Enter the number: "))
order = int(input("Enter the order: "))
print ("Make a choice, 1 for PERMUTATION and 2 for COMBINATION")
user_input = int(input("Enter the choice: "))
print (user_input)
if (user_input == 1):
    print(permutation(num,order))
elif (user_input == 2):
    print(combination(num,order))
else:
    print ("Enter a valid number")
```